# Can the constructible birthday of a choice set come later than the set?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

In the constructible hierarchy we can have subsets of a set with birthdays (first $L$ stage they appear at as elements) that are much later than the birthday of the mother set. For example Cantor's diagonal.

> Can it be the case that some sets can have all choice sets from them having birthdays later than that of the set? That is we have a set that first appear at say $L_\alpha$ stage, while every choice set from it appears at some $L_\beta$ for $\beta> \alpha$, and in particular I'm interested if $\beta > \alpha + \lambda$ for $\alpha; \lambda$ being transfinite ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this can't happen.

Specifically, suppose $A\in L_{\alpha+1}\setminus L_\alpha$ is a set of disjoint nonempty sets. This means that each $X\in A$ is in $L_\alpha$, and moreover there is a formula $\varphi$ such that $\varphi^{L_\alpha}=A$. Consider now the formula $\psi(x)\equiv$ "There is some $y$ such that $\varphi(y)$ and $x$ is the [$L$-least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe#L_can_be_well-ordered) element of $y$." Then $\psi^{L_\alpha}$ is exactly the set of $L$-least elements of elements of $A$.

*If you want to talk about indexed sets and functions instead of transversals of sets of disjoint sets, the argument is basically the same: since all the "ingredients" already live and are locatable in $L_\alpha$, we can build the "pick-the-$L$-least" function in one definable powerset.*

Comment: This has a little wrinkle in that you need to show that the ordering of $L$ is locally definable.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo That's worth doing though.

Comment: Yes. :-) My point is that standard presentations only show how to relativize the ordering to $L_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ limit.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Wait, really? Oops, I definitely should have pointed that out explicitly then. I'm about to go to sleep now, I'll do that (and sketch the proof) sometime tomorrow when I get the chance. Incidentally, do you know a text which does do the local analysis? Now that I know it's not in every presentation I want a good source to suggest, and none of my books on the subject are at hand right now.

Comment: I'll have to think. My books are in the opposite coast from where I am. If I find one and am awake before you are, I'll let you know.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I'm particularily interested in the case where $\alpha$ is non-standard ordinal, especially if it was a non-standard limit ordinal. I just thought that we can have some of the choice sets of some elements of $L_\alpha$ flying above all sets in $L_\alpha$?! That is their birthday is $>\alpha$. You, affirmed that this cannot be, is there a reference to a complete proof?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, does that mean that for every $\alpha$ limit (standard or not), every choice set from an element of $L_\alpha$ is in $L_\alpha$?

Comment: @Zuhair No, on cardinality grounds, that is typically impossible. You will have some choice sets, but many will only appear at later stages.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, I just want to affirm this result, because its *very* important. Can I conclude from what you describe that this is the case for every $L_\alpha$ for a limit $\alpha$, that there would always be some choice sets from elements of $L_\alpha$ that would appear at later stages than $L_\alpha$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Zuhair No, that is not correct. Sometimes all choice sets for members of $L_\alpha$ appear before stage $\alpha$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, OK, then, so its sometimes and sometimes. I understand now.