# Can these limit countable stages of L retain all choice sets of their elements, in them?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Let $\alpha > \omega$ be a countable limit ordinal such that: $$L_\alpha\cong M\prec L_{\omega_1}$$; that is, $L_\alpha$ knows that its countable. I got to know (from comment on answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836290/is-equality-of-cardinality-of-stages-within-a-limit-constructible-stage-always-w/3836299#comment7913306_3836299)) that such a stage would have every two infinite elements of it having a bijection that is an element of it.

Also from a [comment on answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832943/can-the-constructible-birthday-of-a-choice-set-come-later-than-the-set#comment7913075_3832959) to this question. I came to know that not all stages of $L_\alpha$ for a limit $\alpha > \omega$ has all choice sets of elements of them being in them.

So my question is:

> is it possible for a stage $L_\alpha$ to satsify the above condition (knowing that its countable) and at the same time have all choice sets of elements of it being in it?

> I mean is that known to be consistent with $\sf ZF + V=L$?

Comment: You missunderstood something in the comment you mention. If $L_\alpha\cong M\prec L_{\omega_1}$, then $L_\alpha$ certainly does not see that itself is countable.

Comment: Then how you understand the comment? Was it meant that $L_\alpha$ see $\alpha$ as countable? by then it would see any two infinite elements of it as equinumerous, i.e. it has a bijection inside it that witness that equinumerousity. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at all.

For $i\in\omega$ let $X_i=\{0,1\}\times \{i\}$, and let $\mathcal{X}=\{X_i:i\in\omega\}$. There's an obvious bijection between choice functions for $\mathcal{X}$ and reals. So you don't get *all* the choice functions until you get *all* the reals - that is, even granting $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^L$, it's only at $L_{\omega_1}$ that we actually get all the choice functions for $\mathcal{X}$.

---

Things shift into more conventional phrasing if we ask:

> For which $\alpha$ is it the case that $L_\alpha$ is closed under (constructible) powersets - that is, such that $u\in L_\alpha\implies\mathcal{P}^L(u)\in L_\alpha$?

(The point being that subsets of $u$ correspond to choice functions for $\{\{0,1\}\times\{i\}: i\in u\}$.)

These are exactly the **constructible cardinals**, that is, the $\alpha$s which $L$ thinks are cardinals. One direction of this is just the usual proof that $L\models\mathsf{GCH}$. In the other direction, suppose $L\models \vert\alpha\vert=\kappa<\alpha$. Then there is an $X\subseteq \kappa$ coding an isomorphic copy of $L_\alpha$ itself, which of course can't be in $L_\alpha$.

Comment: Yes but does choice necessarily fail inside such $L_\alpha$? I mean is it provable that there is an element in such $L_\alpha$ (that is a set of pairwise disjoint sets) such that there is no choice *set* from it being an element of $L_\alpha$, so all choice sets from it would appear at later stages?

Comment: @Zuhair You appear to be conflating two things, existence of *some* choice functions for each element and existence of *all* (constructible) choice functions for each element. If $\alpha>\omega$ is not an $L$-cardinal there is a $w\in L_\alpha$ such that there are choice functions for $w$ of arbitrarily high $L$-rank below $\vert\alpha\vert^+$. But this is not the same as choice failing in $L_\alpha$ when $\alpha>\omega$ is not an $L$-cardinal: we just need *some*, not *all*, choice functions for each element of $L_\alpha$ to live in $L_\alpha$. Indeed, **every** level of $L$ satisfies choice.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference, I was just asking. So every level of $L$ satisfies choice internally, that's fine!